# Factory Pattern can't understand why the factory

Tags: design-patterns, factory

Looking at this example: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/68670/The-Factory-Pattern

Why can't I instantiate the concrete objects using Reflection like I show bellow, instead of having the extra work of creating a factory?

```
private Bat OrderBat(string choice)
{
   Bat myBat = Reflection.NewObject(choice);


   myBat.clean();
   myBat.applyGrip();
   myBat.applyLogo();
   myBat.applyCover();
   myBat.pack();

   return myBat;
}
```

Comment: And how would the reflection class create the object based on `string choice`? That's right: By implementing the factory pattern.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

that only works when

1) `choice` string directly maps to a `Bat` class names

2) all `Bat` classes have default no-argument constructor

imagine that one day some new `Bat` classes have extra arguments like e.g. color:

```
switch (choice) {  
   case "hardball-yellow": 
      myBat = new HardBallColoredBat(Color.YELLOW); 
      break; 

   case "hardball-white": 
      myBat = new HardBallColoredBat(Color.WHITE); 
      break; 

   case "softball": 
      myBat = new SoftBallBat(); 
      break; 
}
```

by having all this extra code in a factory you can easily modify code for creation of new bats without going throught all the code that uses it.